# Как использовать DateTimePicker C#

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Делаю приложение на C#, которое будет выключать пк после выбора времени, через которое выключить, и нажатия на кнопку. Я смог реализовать это с заданным временем (5,10,15.. минут) через radiobutton, а как сделать чтобы было что-то по типу DomainUpDown и там время пк. Чтобы пользователь там выбирал время. Вооот. Как мне задать domain время пк и считывать оттуда время? Вот пример из другого приложения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для таких целей существует свой элемент. К примеру, `DateTimePicker` - отвечает за DateTime (время, число, месяц итд), которую мы хотим выбрать. Давайте попробуем воспользоватся им:

- Добавим на форму сам элемент.
- Зададим ему `Format` в Time (можно через код `dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;`).
- Зададим ему `ShowUpDown` в `true`.
- Ну и зададим к примеру текущее время (в код: `dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;`).

Готово! На выходе получаем необходимый вам элемент [image: img1]

Само значение у него храниться (как не странно) в `Value`. По этому вы всегда сможете вытащить его, к примеру, в переменную `DateTime selectedTime = dateTimePicker1.Value;`

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую завтра

Comment: @P1NG2WIN это один из стандартных элементов, такой же как Lable, TextBox, DomainUpDown и др. Сами элементы можно глянуть в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/controls-to-use-on-windows-forms)